# Imageview doesn't show image on first try

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, orientation, scaling

I have made an activity where an imageview with fixed sizes shows a picture from a custom destination. The scaling and orientation are already working, but when I start the app, the imageview first shows a little grey box. When I load it again however, it does show the picture like it's supposed to. Can anyone please tell me what's happening here and how I'll be able to fix it? I already googled the problem but I think it has something to do with the sequence in which my code executes..
Here is my code for showing the image:

```
public void refreshImageView(String highlight){
    File image;
    if(highlight==null){
        image=new File(mydb.getCityById(cityId).getPicture());
    }else{
        try{
        image=new File(mydb.getHighlightById(highlightId).getFile());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "There is no file saved for this highlight");
            image=new File("");
        }
    }
    if(image.exists()&&image.toString().endsWith(".jpg")){
        mImagePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        int maxWidth=mImagePreview.getWidth(), maxHeight=mImagePreview.getHeight();
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),options);
        options.inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(options,maxWidth,maxHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
        Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        try{
            mBitmap=checkOrientation(image.getAbsolutePath(),mBitmap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Picture could not be rotated");
        }
        Bitmap bitmapPrev=Bitmap.createBitmap(
                mBitmap.getWidth()+20,
                mBitmap.getHeight()+20,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmapPrev);
        canvas.drawColor(R.color.black);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 10,10,new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
        mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmapPrev);
    }
    else{
        mImagePreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

//method for calculating sample size
private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int maxWidth, int maxHeight){
    final int height=options.outHeight,width=options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize=1;

    if(height>maxHeight || width>maxWidth){
        final int heightRatio=Math.round((float)height/(float)maxHeight),
                widthRatio=Math.round((float)width/(float)maxWidth);
        inSampleSize=heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

//method to check orientation of picture
private Bitmap checkOrientation(String path, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException{
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(path);
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
    switch(orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
}

//method to rotate image
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return rotated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why all that code? The image view can take care of all that loading and scaling!

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
imageView.setScaleType(...FIT_XY);
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: I know, but then the imageview loads the picture in its full size before adjusting it to the scale of the imageview. This makes the loading of the picture very slow and that's why I did it like this, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You should then use the subsampling-scale-image-view library. It does all this and more. Get it at https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view